# При get запросе к сайту, статус запроса равен 403. Как это исправить?

Tags: python, requests, get

При get запросе к сайту Авито, статус запроса равен 403, из-за чего не получается заполучить код страницы. Можно ли это как то исправить? Я только начал работать с библиотекой requests, так что поправьте меня если что-то неправильно написал.
Заранее спасибо.

Код:

```
import requests 
from fake_useragent import UserAgent 
 
url = "https://www.avito.ru/" 
 
headers = { 
 'Accept': '*/*', 
 'User-Agent': UserAgent().chrome 
 } 
 
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers) 
src = req.text 
 
print(req.status_code)
```

Comment: у avito скорее всего есть что то блокирующее для таких запросов, сайт avito открывается после пары таких запусков?

Comment: почитайте вот это, скорее всего решит все проблемы https://developers.avito.ru/api-catalog
https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/3.0.0.md

Comment: Может у авито авторизация по токенам и вы не проходите. Попробуйте сперва получить токен а затем передавать его в запросе на авито.